# Оптимизация Flask

Tags: highload, нагрузочное-тестирование

Есть веб-приложение на Flask, стало интересно протестировать его на возможную нагрузку. Взял простенькую стартовую страницу, почти полностью статичную, бд на которой вообще не задействуется. Начал на ней создавать нагрузку через JMeter, после чего поник:

Если начать пользоваться сайтом при 15 запросах в секунду, тупняки ощущаются, при 50 пользоваться сайтом вообще не приятно. И это ведь загрузка одной единственной html страницы, без всех сопутствующий css, js, png и т.п.

**Что делать чтобы увеличить производительность хотя бы раз в 100?**

Тестировал на своем рабочем macbook pro с веб-сервером Werkzeug и такие плачевные результаты показал он, а на vps за 200рублей с Apache2 результаты еще хуже

Comment: Во-первых, измерить, что именно во фласке тормозит, иначе непонятно что оптимизировать. Во-вторых, потратить больше чем 200 рублей

Comment: В-третьих, веб-сервер Werkzeug КАТЕГОРИЧЕСКИ НЕЛЬЗЯ использовать для продакшена! Возьмите gunicorn или uwsgi, запустите несколько воркеров, поставьте перед ним nginx (ни в коем случае не apache2) и повторите измерения - только после это будет можно о чём-то разговаривать.

Comment: @andreymal, мне стало интересно, почему ни в коем случае не apache?

Comment: @Mattern потому что он в принципе медленный по своей архитектуре (не асинхронный, в отличие от nginx)